# How to make text strikethrough when hovered in elm (elm-ui)?

Tags: elm, elm-ui

Basically I want to make the text strikethrough when hovered. This doesn't work easily with

```
el [ mouseOver [Font.strike] ] (text "some text")
```

as it would with

```
el [ mouseOver [Background.color someColor] ] (text "some other text")
```

because `Font.strike` is a `Attribute msg` whereas `Background.color` is of type `Attr decorative msg`

Does anyone konw how to achieve described behavior with something like `Font.strike`?

I would also accept non `elm-ui` solutions if not possible otherwise.

Comment: [`Html.Attributes.map`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/html/latest/Html-Attributes#map) could be used for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like you already pointed out, `mouseOver` requires a `Attr decorative msg`. It uses `CSS` for the hover (hence the limitations), which takes care of applying the style on mouse over and clears it on mouse out.

For the general case, we have to detect mouse over/out ourselves, using `Element.Events`. We also need to keep track of this state in our `Model`. Then we can apply the `Font.strike` attribute conditionally depending on the model.

We can listen for these events on an `Element.el`

```
Events.onMouseEnter Enter
  :: Events.onMouseLeave Leave
  :: style
```

, where `style` is either `[ Font.strike ]` or `[]`, depending on the model.

Full code and working demo here: https://ellie-app.com/bNjP6CbGrLJa1